# Calling into Foundation from non-Cocoa app, do I need NSRunLoop?

Tags: avfoundation, nsrunloop

I am writing a program a plugin for a program that does not exist in the Cocoa environment (think C++ command line program let's say). If of interest, this is the v8 node add-on system. I'd like this plugin to record the screen, and thus make use of AVCaptureSession, etc. So essentially, something like:

```
void start(/*entry*/)
{
    // No run loop is *necessarily* present.
    AVCaptureSession * session = ...
}

void stop (/*entry*/)
{
    // etc..
}
```

In actuality, I will probably be starting a new pthread to do this stuff in so that none of it is blocking. My question is, how much of the surrounding Foundation infrastructure do I need to set up. I almost certainly need an @autoreleasepool { }, but should I actually be starting up my own default NSRunLoop to run in the thread, if not I get the impression that any trickiness in AVCapture and so forth may fail:

```
BOOL isStillRecording = YES;
void start(/*entry*/)
{
   // setup avcapture and what have you.
   NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop new];
   while (isStillRecording && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
}

void stop(/**entry**/)
{
   // kill avcapture, maybe through async_dispatch to not stop on the start up.
   isStillRecording = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Actually, I take it back. It looks like you need to use the current runloop to get some delegate callbacks, like `AVCaptureFileOutput`'s. This creates a quicktime movie of the screen and microphone fine:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface Capturer() <AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate>

@property(nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property(nonatomic) AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieOutput;
@property(nonatomic, copy) void(^finishBlock)(NSError*);

@end

@implementation Capturer
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup {
    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // capture the screen
    CGDirectDisplayID displayId = CGMainDisplayID();
    AVCaptureScreenInput *screenInput = [[AVCaptureScreenInput alloc] initWithDisplayID:displayId];

    [self.session addInput:screenInput];

    // capture microphone input
    AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:nil];
    [self.session addInput:audioInput];

    self.movieOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    [self.session addOutput:self.movieOutput];
}

- (void)start {
    [self.session startRunning];
    NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath]] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:movieURL error:nil];
    NSLog(@"recording to %@", movieURL.path);
    [self.movieOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:movieURL recordingDelegate:self];
}

- (void)stop:(void (^)(NSError *))finishBlock {
    self.finishBlock = finishBlock;
   [self.movieOutput stopRecording];
}

// MARK: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Finished recording to %@ with error %@", outputFileURL.path, error);
    [self.session stopRunning];
    self.finishBlock(error);
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Capturer *c = [[Capturer alloc] init];
        NSRunLoop   *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

        [c start];

        // record 10s' worth
        __block BOOL finished = NO;
        [c performSelector:@selector(stop:) withObject:^(NSError *error) {
            finished = YES;
        } afterDelay:10];

        // cribbed from https://gist.github.com/syzdek/3220789
        while(!finished && [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2]]) NSLog(@"waiting");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**previously**

I've used `AVFoundation` in command line apps and I didn't need `NSRunLoop`. I needed to

1. create an `@autoreleasepool` (as you say)
2. as `AVFoundation` is quite asynchronous, use a semaphore to make sure I didn't exit before processing had finished.